# What's the R way to do the following group by?

Tags: r, group-by

I have some dataset like this:

```
# date     # value    class
1984-04-01 95.32384   A
1984-04-01 39.86818   B
1984-07-01 43.57983   A
1984-07-01 10.83754   B
```

Now I would like to group the data by data and subtract the value of class B from class A.
I looked into ddply, summarize, melt and aggregate but cannot quite get what I want. Is there a way to do it easily? Note that I have exactly two values per date one of class A and one of class B. I mean i could re-arrange it into two dfs order it by date and class and merge it again, but I feel there is a more R way to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of is to use `dcast` from the `reshape2` package, to create a data-frame with one date per row and columns `A` and `B`,  then use `transform` to do `A-B`:

```
df <- data.frame( date = rep(seq(as.Date('1984-04-01'), 
                                 as.Date('1984-04-01') + 3, by=1), 
                            1, each=2),
                  class = rep(c('A','B'), 4),
                  value = sample(1:8))

require(reshape2)
df_wide <- dcast(df, date  ~ class, value_var = 'value')

> df_wide
        date A B
1 1984-04-01 8 7
2 1984-04-02 6 1
3 1984-04-03 3 4
4 1984-04-04 5 2

> transform( df_wide, A_B = A - B )

        date A B A_B
1 1984-04-01 8 7   1
2 1984-04-02 6 1   5
3 1984-04-03 3 4  -1
4 1984-04-04 5 2   3
```

Answer (score 7):

Assuming this data frame (generated as in Prasad's post but with a `set.seed` for reproducibility):

```
set.seed(123)
DF <- data.frame( date = rep(seq(as.Date('1984-04-01'), 
                                 as.Date('1984-04-01') + 3, by=1), 
                            1, each=2),
                  class = rep(c('A','B'), 4),
                  value = sample(1:8))
```

then we consider seven solutions:

1) **zoo** can give us a one line solution (not counting the `library` statement):

```
library(zoo)
z <- with(read.zoo(DF, split = 2), A - B)
```

giving this `zoo` series:

```
> z
1984-04-01 1984-04-02 1984-04-03 1984-04-04 
        -3          3          3         -5
```

Also note that `as.data.frame(z)` or `data.frame(time = time(z), value = coredata(z))` gives a data frame; however, you may wish to leave it as a zoo object since it is a time series and other operations are more conveniently done on it in this form, e.g. `plot(z)`

2) **sqldf** can also give a one statement solution (aside from the `library` invocation):

```
> library(sqldf)
> sqldf("select date, sum(((class = 'A') - (class = 'B')) * value) as value
+ from DF group by date")
        date value
1 1984-04-01    -3
2 1984-04-02     3
3 1984-04-03     3
4 1984-04-04    -5
```

3) **tapply** can be used as the basis of a solution inspired by the sqldf solution:

```
> with(DF, tapply(((class =="A") - (class == "B")) * value, date, sum))
1984-04-01 1984-04-02 1984-04-03 1984-04-04 
        -3          3          3         -5
```

4) **aggregate** can be used in the same way as `sqldf` and `tapply` above (although a slightly different solution also based on `aggregate` has already appeared):

```
> aggregate(((DF$class=="A") - (DF$class=="B")) * DF["value"], DF["date"], sum)
        date value
1 1984-04-01    -3
2 1984-04-02     3
3 1984-04-03     3
4 1984-04-04    -5
```

5) **summaryBy** from the doBy package can provide yet another solution although it does need a `transform` to help it along:

```
> library(doBy)
> summaryBy(value ~ date, transform(DF, value = ((class == "A") - (class == "B")) * value), FUN = sum, keep.names = TRUE)
        date value
1 1984-04-01    -3
2 1984-04-02     3
3 1984-04-03     3
4 1984-04-04    -5
```

6) **remix** from the remix package can do it too but with a `transform` and features  particularly pretty output:

```
> library(remix)
> remix(value ~ date, transform(DF, value = ((class == "A") - (class == "B")) * value), sum)
value ~ date
============

+------+------------+-------+-----+
|                           | sum |
+======+============+=======+=====+
| date | 1984-04-01 | value | -3  |
+      +------------+-------+-----+
|      | 1984-04-02 | value | 3   |
+      +------------+-------+-----+
|      | 1984-04-03 | value | 3   |
+      +------------+-------+-----+
|      | 1984-04-04 | value | -5  |
+------+------------+-------+-----+
```

7) **summary.formula** in the Hmisc package also has pretty output:

```
> library(Hmisc)
> summary(value ~ date, data = transform(DF, value = ((class == "A") - (class == "B")) * value), fun = sum, overall = FALSE)
value    N=8

+----+----------+-+-----+
|    |          |N|value|
+----+----------+-+-----+
|date|1984-04-01|2|-3   |
|    |1984-04-02|2| 3   |
|    |1984-04-03|2| 3   |
|    |1984-04-04|2|-5   |
+----+----------+-+-----+
```

Comment: That's helluva answer! kudos. I tried sqldf before but always get a missing dbname error. Do I have do something to initialize it (apart from require)?

Comment: Normally its not necessary to specify a `dbname` in sqldf.  You just load it using `library(sqldf)` and then issue an `sqldf` statement. If its using sqlite or h2 then the default is to use an in memory database so no name is needed.  Maybe you have the RMySQL or RgpSQL package loaded?  If you do then sqldf will assume you want to use those databases rather than sqlite in which case you either have to supply a dbname or else use the default name.  Detach RMySQL or RpgSQL if you have them loaded or else you can use `options(sqldf.driver="sqlite")` to force sqlite despite what you have loaded.

Comment: @ran2, If you use RMySQL a lot you might prefer to have sqldf work with that rather than sqlite.  By default sqldf uses a `dbname="test"` with RMySQL so if you set up such a database in MySQL then you can use sqldf with that MySQL database.  Alternately you can change the default dbname for MySQL to something else using `options(RMySQL.dbname = "someotherdatabasename")` .

Answer (score 5):

In base R, I would approach the problem by using `aggregate` and `sum`.  This works by converting each value of class B to its negative:

(Using the data provided by @PrasadChalasani)

```
df <- within(df, value[class=="B"] <- -value[class=="B"])
aggregate(df$value, by=list(date=df$date), sum)

        date x
1 1984-04-01 3
2 1984-04-02 2
3 1984-04-03 2
4 1984-04-04 1
```

Comment: Wow this question, is more interesting to me than I initially thought it would be.

Comment: What's this? @Andrie providing an answer using base R instead of plyr? Wonders will never cease ;-)

Comment: @GavinSimpson, I know, it's a shocker.  But @Chase is so quick to the draw with ddply solutions nowadays...

Answer (score 4):

For the record, I like the reshape option the best. Here's a plyr option using summarise:

```
library(plyr)

ddply(df, "date", summarise
    , A = value[class == "A"]
    , B = value[class == "B"]
    , A_B = value[class == "A"] - value[class == "B"]
)
```

Comment: +1 appreciate the record :) . Used ddply before which is why named it, in the hope of not having to switch the toolbox. Still though I do not find this too intuitive...

Comment: @ran2 - try running `dlply(df, "date")` to see what plyr is doing when we group by `date`. We still have the problem of needing to subtract values from different rows, which is why we use `[` to get the proper row, essentially doing the reshape step by group. I think this may be one of those times where embracing the `~` and using reshape(2) is the "optimal" solution. Maybe an R-purist will come along and give a base R solution too, but I bet it will look very similar to Prasad's answer.

Comment: Thx for the elaborate explanation. I am really trying to solve these kind of problems more and more in R instead of going back to SQL which is also cumbersome for other reasons like loosing attributes etc. Yet it working with results from different lines isn't a strength of SQL neither :)